# How can I link my css file with my html in sublimetext 2?

Tags: html, css

My main doubt is the part of `href`.How can i avoid using the full link of the file as saved in my harddisk so that i dont need to change it while transferring through ftp.I also want to know how you can view your html files being developed that has been linked to different css files on your desktop web browser like chrome.

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML file is stored in a directory, and your CSS files are stored, for example, in a `css` subdirectory, all you need to do is add

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css">
```

to the `<head>` tags of your HTML file, and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the same folder as your HTML file you will simply type the name of the file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Let's say that your style.css file is in another folder called css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

By playing a "/" in front of your file name it is saying that it should look for the "css" folder starting from the root folder instead of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative paths. If the css stylesheet is in the same folder as the html use href="style.css". If it's in a folder that is in the same folder as the html use href="styles/style.css". If you need to go up a folder use href="../style.css".